# Tensor Notation

Tags: tensors, tensor-rank

I'm just starting to learn about tensors, and have a question.

I'm looking at the statement $\Lambda_{\mu}\,^{\alpha}= \eta_{\mu\nu}\eta^{\alpha\beta}\Lambda^{\nu}\,_{\beta}$

What is the difference between $\Lambda_{\beta}\,^{\nu}$ and $\Lambda^{\nu}\,_{\beta}$ ?

Comment: no difference ${{{}}}$ unless there is $.$ in the space.

Comment: oh so it doesn't matter which way round I write it? So $\Lambda_{\mu}\,^{\alpha}= \eta_{\mu\nu}\eta^{\alpha\beta}\Lambda^{\nu}\,_{\beta}$ is the same as $\Lambda_{\mu}\,^{\alpha}= \eta_{\mu\nu}\eta^{\alpha\beta}\Lambda_{\beta}\,^{\nu}$

Comment: yes, since you can interchange the differentials while transformation for $x \to \bar x$. what is $\eta$ BTW?? looks like metric, but we usually use $g$ for metric.

Comment: $g$ is used for Riemann metric, $η$ for Minkowski (pseudo-)metric. And the difference is that the one is the transpose of the other, which does not matter for diagonal or symmetric matrices.

Comment: Why is there a space at all? Symmetry allows one to change the order or variables and has nothing to do with the space. One usually writes $\nu$ right above the $\beta$.

Comment: @apurv I would regard writing indices on top of each other as sloppy notation.  Each column should have only one index in it, either up or down.

Answer (score 3):

$Λ_β{}^ν$ has first a covariant and then a contravariant index and thus describes a tensor $Λ_β{}^ν({\bf θ}^β\otimes {\bf e}_ν)$ in $V^*\otimes V=Hom(V^*)$, while in $Λ^ν{}_β({\bf e}_ν⊗{\bf θ}^β)$ the positions are exchanged, so it is in  $V\otimes V^*=Hom(V)$. These tensor products are trivially isomorphic, but in the strict sense different. As matrices, by construction $Λ_β{}^ν$ is the two-times Riesz dual of $Λ^ν{}_β$, meaning for the canonical Minkowski metric the components are the same, except that the mixed space-time components have a switched sign.